# How can I simulate a keypress event?

Tags: dart

For tests I need to simulate the using typing in form inputs. I've tried creating a `KeyboardEvent` and dispatching it on an input, but that doesn't seem to work. Is there the equivalent of `Element.click()` hiding out somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `WidgetTester` library?
With it you can simulate input text on the `textFields` with the `enterText` method and the finder to locate the desired `textField`:

```
testWidgets('Add and remove a todo', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  // Build the widget
  await tester.pumpWidget(const TodoList());

  // Enter 'hi' into the TextField.
  await tester.enterText(find.byType(TextField), 'hi');
});
```

font: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/widget/tap-drag